# Printing A String In Alphabetical Order (H! Assembly)

Tags: assembly

Hi I'm a college student taking a course in computer architecture/organization and we got this assignment where we have to write a H1 assembly program that reads a string and prints it in alphabetical order. I've been thinking that what I could try is to push each letter into the stack in order of lowest to highest ASCII code and then delocating each in a loop, but I'm not sure how exactly I should go about that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't `push` the string on the stack! Input the string in a memory buffer, sort the contents alphabetically (using any suitable sorting method), and output what is in the buffer.

Comment: Try it in C.  If you can already do it in C then translate the algorithm into assembly.  If you can't do it in C, then you're looking for an algorithm (which, in concept, is independent of assembly code).

Comment: If you can only read 1 input char at a time anyway, then sure, insertion-sort on the fly mixed with input is reasonable. Or if you can only print 1 char at a time, 1 pass of selection sort per output could work.  (But you'd need a way to mark off already-read positions.)